# Reactjs - how to change styling of inputValidator of sweetalert2 popup

Tags: reactjs, sweetalert2

I'm currently using sweetalert2 to have the user select a file.  If the user does not select a file I am using inputValidator to post an error message on the popup.  The default error message puts a red border around the file input box.  Is it possible to remove the red border or to customize it (change it to green/blue)?  Here is the code I am using.

```
const MySwal = withReactContent(Swal)

    MySwal.fire({
        confirmButtonText: 'Submit File',
        showCancelButton: true,
        title: "<b>Submit New File</b>",
        input: 'file',
        focusConfirm: false,
        allowOutsideClick: false,
        inputValidator: (value) => {
          if(!value){
            return "Please select a file"
          }
        }
```

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never used `Swal` before, but what you can do is to give the input field a `customClass` and give it border as you wish.

[source](https://sweetalert2.github.io/#usage)

Hope that helped!

Comment: And of course, you can inspect the input field always to see what should be changed!

Comment: Strange, looks like the only thing the input box is responding to is change in padding.  Thanks for the advice I'll keep playing around with it

Comment: Indeed. Can you make a code sandbox, then I can follow along!?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-pascal-wpjz2

See the red outline when you try to submit it without a file.  If possible I'd like to get rid of that.  Thanks!